# double TryParse confusion

Tags: c#, .net, double, visual-studio-2015, linqpad

So I was dinking around in [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) and noticed something odd, I get same result in Visual Studio testing code Unit Tests.

I was playing with all the different TryParse for the numerical datatypes. During this I noticed that double.TryParse is acting a bit different then the rest.

For example:

```
var doubleStr = double.MinValue.ToString();
//doubleStr = -1.79769313486232E+308

double result;
var result = double.TryParse(doubleStr, out result);
//result is returning false
```

All other datatypes with the MinValue are not having this trouble:

```
var floatStr = float.MinValue.ToString();
//floatStr = -3.402823E+38 

float result2;
float.TryParse(floatStr, out result2);
//result = True
```

Any body know why double is the only one that false to parse the string version of it's MinValue property back to an actual double?

I am not seeing why this is different off hand. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Pretty sure this has to do with the exponential notation with .ToString() causing it to drop some digits.

Comment: Be interesting to see doubleStr and floatStr values.

Comment: MinValue as string (-1.79769313486232E+308) fails. Bump that last decimal to 1 (-1.79769313486231E+308) and it succeeds. Probably some breaking point in between.

Comment: @JamesR. updated with those values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get a string that can be surely re-parsed as a `double`, use the [`"R"`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#RFormatString) (round-trip) format string:

```
double.Parse(double.MinValue.ToString("R"))
```

In other formats, the string you get may generally re-parse to a different value, due to rounding. With `double.MinValue`, this gets especially worse, since the different value it *would* re-parse to is outside of the range of `double`. Hence the parse failing.

Comment: Thank you. That is a good find. MSDN says The round-trip ("R") format specifier is used to ensure that a numeric value that is converted to a string will be parsed back into the same numeric value. This format is supported only for the Single, Double, and BigInteger types.